# ios6 What’s New with MapKit mkmapview

Tags: mkmapview, ios6

What’s New with MapKit api in the iOS 6?

any links/tutorial somewhere ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far into Apple's developer site have you looked?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011959

Comment: I took a look, it is helpfull thanks